# How to set a CONSTRAINT for mobile no. field using CREATE query in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints, sql-like, createquery

I have tried all the combinations of **LIKE** and **NOT LIKE** but unable to set a **CONSTRAINT** for mobile number field, as I want to create table using

```
  CREATE TABLE patient (
  pname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
  mobNo VARCHAR(15),
  CONSTRAINT checkMob CHECK(mobNo NOT LIKE '^[^A-Z]%')
  );
```

but getting error while inserting values, and **i want numbers only in mobile number field**.

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

> i want numbers only in mobile number field

```sql
CREATE TABLE patient ( pname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
                       mobNo VARCHAR(15),
                       CONSTRAINT checkMob CHECK(mobNo REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')
                     );
```